In Celery I want my tasks to run sequentially
In Celery I want my tasks to run sequentially! As they dependent on each other! But the main issue as follows: Job_1 was submitted which has two tasks: Task_1_1 and Task_2_1. Now, it works perfectly fine. However, if Task_1_1 was running and Job_2 was submitted, Task_1_2 will run after Task_1_1 and not Task_2_1! After Task_1_2 finishes, Task_2_1 and Task_2_2 will run! But I want Job_1 to finish completely before jumping to Job_2!
I want Job_1 to finish after Job_2 starts!
